# Does python delete a list while there is a copy of it

Tags: python

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
listb = lista[:]
lista = 'somethingelse'
listb.pop()
```

So now, the list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] still exist, or it is removed from the internal memory, or it is changed into [1, 2, 3, 4] with listb?

Answer (score 4):

Let's see your code line by line.

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This would point the name `lista` to the list having values `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` (let's call it *list#1*).

```
listb = lista[:]
```

This would make a copy of the list above, and point the name `listb` to that copy (let's call it *list#2*); now essentially there are 2 lists with equal contents (*list#1* and *list#2*)

```
lista = 'somethingelse'
```

This would cause the name `lista` to point to the string `'somethingelse'`; the **reference count** of *list#1* will be decreased by 1; if nothing is pointing to it anymore, its memory will be freed.

```
listb.pop()
```

Removes the last element from *list#2*, and returns it; *list#2* will be equal to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. *list#1*, if it still exists, will not be changed by this operation.

With *only* the code above, the list object that you initially stored in `lista` (*list#1*) would neither be changed, nor would it exist any more in the memory* when the `listb.pop()` is executed.

---

*) though in Jython and other non-CPython implementations the garbage collection might be delayed so it could still be consuming memory.

Answer (score 2):

In the first line you create a list referenced by `lista`. In the second line you copy this list and set a reference by `listb`. In line three, you remove the reference to the list of line one, so the first list is garbage collected. Still the list referenced by `listb` exists, which is modified in the last line.